# i started getting cors error out of the blue and its not working at all despite trying various fixes

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, cors

My app was working fine, i was using my app locally  while fetching data from the coincap api (worked perfectly then out of nowhere it didn't). Ive tried various solutions but still get the error. Can anyone help

here is the error:

**'Access to fetch at 'http://api.coincap.io/v2/assets' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.'**

Below is the server I have setup:

```
import express from 'express'
import cors from 'cors'
import mongoose from 'mongoose'
import {userRouter} from './routes/users.js'
import {profileRouter} from './routes/profile.js'

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.options('*', cors())
app.use(express.json());
app.use('/auth', userRouter)
app.use('/profile', profileRouter)


mongoose.connect('my connection')


app.listen(5000,()=>{
    console.log(`listening on port 5000...`)
```

And below is the `useffect` where the problem starts on the client side:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const crypto = async () => {
      try{
      const res = await fetch("http://api.coincap.io/v2/assets?limit=30")
      const data = await res.json();
      setCrypto(data.data)
    } catch(err){
        console.error(err)
      }     
    }
    crypto();
  }, [])
```

Comment: Wait so you are fetching data no longer from your own API running on `localhost:5000` but rather some external API that you have no code-control over, unless that's your own deployed API `api.coincap.io` ? Other than that I'm successfully fetching data in my DevTools from that API except when I did, like your code is doing, use `http` instead of `https` it's blocked if the current site (like *stackoverflow*) is loaded with `HTTPS` - which your `http://localhost:3000` is not. But anyways try to modify the fetched url to use `https..` and tell me if the blockage persists.

Comment: yes im using my own api plus fetching data and posting data to a mongodb database (basically so users can have an account and save specific coins to favorites) . then on the homepage fetching data from coincap as a list of the top ranked crypto coins

Comment: fantastic, that fixed it. much appreciated good sir!!!